# Auto responders to only certain email addresses in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I'm trying to set up an auto responder to only certain people in Gmail. I'm aware you can go to –*Settings* → *General* → *Vacation responder* to set a global response, but I'm trying to setup almost a filter that says

> IF EMAIL IS "john@example.com" SAY "Im not here at the moment, back next week" IF NOT "john@example.com" DO NOTHING

Is that possible in Gmail?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Unfortunately, unlike the vacation autoresponder which only sends the message *once* to the sender, you'll end up sending the message every time you receive a message.

First, you need to turn on the [**Canned Responses** lab](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2008/10/new-in-labs-canned-responses.html) and set one up.

(To create a canned response, start by composing a new message, then in the context menu of the compose window choose *Canned responses* → *New canned response…*.)

Once you've got your canned response, now you need a filter.

Create a filter with the trigger `from:john@example.com` and choose as the action *Send canned response:* and choose the canned response you just created. You may want to make the filter more specific and/or choose other things to do with the message. (There are lots of posts here that cover Gmail and filters. Look under the [gmail-filters](/questions/tagged/gmail-filters) tag.)

Now, whenever a message matches your criteria, a response with your canned text will be sent immediately back. As I mentioned, however, this will happen with every message that trips your filter.

Comment: Thats great - Thanks, How did you input a tag in a post i havnt come across that before ?

Comment: `[tag:tag-name]`. Of course, you can just hit the edit link and see the Markdown for yourself.

Comment: Sorry that skipped my mind - one thing when you get a response back it comes from `name+canned.response@gmail.com` is there a way to stop it adding the `canned.respinse` part to your email address ?

Comment: Asked (but not answered) here: [Is there a way to avoid "+canned.response" in the email address using Gmail's canned response feature](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/44214)