# EXCLUDE email addresses from autoresponder?

Tags: gmail-filters

I know you can create a canned response that will only send to certain emails, but I have a much smaller group of people (internal office) that I don't want the response sent to, rather than those I do.

Is there a way to EXCLUDE email addresses from an auto-responder?

That way my internal office won't get the responder every time they CC me, which is a lot. And instead all customers, clients, inquiries can see that I'm away.

Comment: The auto-responder will only send to an email address _once_, not every time you receive a message from that address, so your co-workers shouldn't get flooded with "away" messages.

Comment: To pile onto Al's note, it looks like it responds again after four days if you're still gone.

Comment: Ah, yes. Thank you @panhandel. (Serves me right for not looking at the settings page first, where it says so right there.)

Answer (score 3):

The only option besides the date range used with the Gmail vacation responder is to have responses go only to people in your contacts. (Otherwise it's every address that sends you email.)

The only way to do what you want (with just Gmail) is to use canned responses as described in [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/49138/354) but to use ***negation*** in your search criteria:

```
-from:jdoe@example.com -from:bsmith@example.com -from:ajohnson@example.com
```

The trouble is that you'll send the response to every message, so if you've missed someone, or one of your customers contacts you a dozen times, they'll get the response back every time.